# Millennium Falcon - cannons above cockpit?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

This has been nagging at me for quite some time:

**Where are the cannons that are seen firing above the cockpit of the Millennium Falcon?**

Their use can be distinctly seen approximately 40 seconds after dropping out of hyperspace near what was Alderaan. A lone patrolling TIE fighter overtakes them and Han throws a quick switch in the ceiling, firing as the fighter zooms past.

[image: Animated GIF showing the view forward from behind the seats in the cockpit of the Millennium Falcon. The backs of Han's, Luke's, Obi-Wan's and Chewie's heads are visible against the view of empty space framed in the windows. Han raises his right arm to the top of the cockpit as a flash is visible in space ahead, and a TIE fighter streaks past from behind.]

I just rewatched the scene mentioned above, just to confirm I'm not imagining things. Then I went and looked at various shots of the Millennium Falcon, models and in the movies.

Just to be safe, I allowed that it might actually have been the TIE that took a quick pot-shot, but to me it's definitely Han shooting first (har har!)

There's nothing I can identify as looking like cannons above the cockpit.

Comment: +1 just for asking a question about canon cannons!

Comment: What is going on with canon\legends around here? I know that canon takes priority, but are legends answers still acceptable?

Comment: It's super hard to understand your question, I had to read it around 3 time before I was sure what you were asking. Maybe edit to clarify. :)

Comment: Heh, ouch. I try to compress a lot into sentences and loathe the modern trend to short sentences, but I really thought I phrased the content fairly clear and linear. I'll do a bit of editing. :)

Comment: Thanks for the edited addition of the video. Though I noticed only a **bam!** not a ***boom!**, so the manga is clearly wrong! ;)

Comment: @erdiede - Legends-only answers are still fine (see my comic strips below) but don't expect them to get lots of upvotes. People tend to prefer canon answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel)) indicates that the flash you see was a strike (by the TIE fighter) on the Falcon's deflector shields:

> “A survivor, maybe—someone who might know what happened,” Luke ventured hopefully.
>   Ben Kenobi’s next words shattered more than that hope. “That’s an Imperial fighter.”
>   Chewbacca suddenly gave an angry bark. **A huge flower of destruction blossomed outside the port, battering the freighter violently.** A tiny, double-winged ball raced past the cockpit port.

and from the [junior novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(junior_novelization))

> As if in response to Ben’s words, **a huge explosion burst outside the
>   cockpit window, then an Imperial TIE fighter streaked past the Falcon.**
>   The Twin Ion Engine ship was immediately recognizable by its two
>   hexagonal solar array wings on either side of a small, spherical
>   command pod.

You can actually see the explosion from the rear view in the [Manga adaptation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Manga:_A_New_Hope) (**BAM! BOOM!**)

[image]

And from the top-down view in the 2015 comic adaptation [A New Hope: The Special Edition](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_A_New_Hope_-_The_Special_Edition) (**WHANG!**)

[image]

Comment: _A huge flower of destruction blossomed outside the port..._ Didn't really translate as such on screen 

Comment: @Daft - Don't make me have to come over and WHANG! you...

Comment: Novel **and** comics quotes! I'm going to have to go with this one as the answer! Many thanks!

Comment: so, basically what my answer said, just with different sources? hmm... want to upvote my answer (if you haven't already)? I'll upvote your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

**There are a few reasons to believe it was actually the TIE fighter shooting at the *Millennium Falcon*, and not the *Falcon* firing those shots.**

1. The *Millennium Falcon* has multiple weapons at its disposal, None of which are *above* the cockpit.

   - upper quad-laser cannon - these are on the top of the ship, to the *left* of the cockpit
   - lower quad-laser cannon - these are on the belly of the ship, to the *left* of the cockpit
   - concussion missiles - these are at the front, to the *left* of the cockpit

     [image: Falcon cross-section]

   Since none of the weapons are directly above the cockpit, it doesn't make sense for those shots to be coming from the *Falcon*.
2. The TIE Fighter wasn't visible from the cockpit until *after* the flashing light from the shot/explosion, so it wasn't the *Falcon* firing. The *Falcon* wouldn't have fired yet since there was nothing to shoot at in front of it. 
   Kenobi had asked Han to avoid Imperial entanglements, and in fact agreed to pay *extra* to ensure it. It is therefore unlikely that Han would immediately fire at a TIE fighter the second he saw one. 
   It makes much more sense for the TIE Fighter, on the other hand, to shoot at the *Falcon* since

   - the Empire is evil and likes to shoot at people, and
   - it was *possibly* doing so to get the *Falcon* to chase after it in order to bring the *Falcon* within range of the Death Star's tractor beam.

All this leads us to believe that it was actually the TIE fighter shooting at the *Millennium Falcon*, and not the *Falcon* firing those shots.

Comment: I need to watch that scene in single frame, because the timing just doesn't seem to point at the TIE firing. As for Han firing, despite being asked not to: as if that would stop him! ;) Personally, I'm simply thinking "they goofed", but surely there is a "canon retconn" explanation?

Comment: @Marakai The TIE Fighter wasn't visible from the cockpit until after the flashing from the shot/explosion, so it wasn't the Falcon firing. The Falcon wouldn't have fired since there was nothing to shoot at in front of it.

Comment: confused - you say no weapons are above the cockpit, then you highlight that the upper quad-laser cannon is "above the cockpit"...