# Did the Empire know the Falcon was going to Alderaan?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

During ANH, Han, Chewbacca, Luke, Obi-Wan and the two droids have left Tatooine aboard the Falcon just in front of the search troops (they fled under blaster blows).
At this point, the Empire know that the "two droids they are looking for" are on board the Falcon.

**Did the Empire know the Falcon was going to Alderaan, right after the escape from Tatooine?**

When the Falcon arrived near Alderaan, a TIE fighter attacked them, then they followed it right to the Death Star. Did they stop all the ships that went on the planet after it exploded?

Or did the empire kidnap the Falcon because he knew the droids were on board?
Was the empire just "lucky" to catch the ship that contained precisely what it was looking for (the plans of the Death Star)?

Comment: Well, the Death Star is a military base. So they have sentries flying around. The TIE didn't attack them after all, it made a run home once it had detected them and they it to report back. Then the Empire made a cross check about the make and model and immediately realised that a YT-1300 had escaped from Tatooine with the droids they were looking for. That was enough of a coincidance to demand further investigation... And anyway the Empire is more the board first ask nicely never kind of government...

Comment: Note that Tarkin picked Alderaan to leverage Leia and she told them to take the plans to Alderaan, so it's not a coincidence that the plans ended up back in the vicinity of Vader/Tarkin

Comment: @Valorum How did Tarkin/Vader know that plans had to be bring on Alderaan ?

Comment: @BMWurm In this topic, "The film's official novelisation indicates that the flash you see was a strike (by the TIE fighter) on the Falcon's deflector shields"  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125700/millenium-falcon-cannons-above-cockpit/125702#125702

Comment: @iammg - They didn't. They went to Alderaan to leverage Leia into giving up the rebel base. Their plan was to find out the location of the base, go to the base (where the plans would likely be heading) then blow it (and the plans) up

Comment: @Valorum And they would have succeeded if they had started their firing sequence earlier. You know, charge all capacitors and everything, not waiting around until the order to fire came...  and then go through the whole process that was needed for Alderaan. They knew they would be firing on Yavin 4. 10 seconds and Yavin 4 would have been toast ... alongside the Death Star... making the destruction of the plans kind off a moot point, but still...

Comment: @BMWurm - It's jarring for me to see "and they would have succeeded" when it's not followed by "if it wasn't for those darn kids!"

Comment: @BMWurm: In addition to the Death Star being a military base -- justifying regular sentries -- it had just blown up Alderaan.  It would make sense after such a procedure to have TIE fighters scout the remains and investigate any surviving vessels.  Which furthermore explains their actions against the *Falcon*.  (The scene described below happens *after* they capture the *Falcon*.)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, it is clear from the scene between Vader and Tarkin that they had not expected the Millennium Falcon to come back to the Alderaan system.

```
                             TARKIN
                 Yes.

                             VOICE
                      (over intercom)
                 We've captured a freighter entering 
                 the remains of the Alderaan system. 
                 It's markings match those of a ship 
                 that blasted its way out of Mos 
                 Eisley.

                             VADER
                 They must be trying to return the 
                 stolen plans to the princess. She 
                 may yet be of some use to us.
```

It is only at this point that they decide to let the princess escape, so that she will lead them to the rebel base.  Had they been expecting the ship to travel to Alderaan, they would have made their plans ahead of time.